# TimeZone input in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, timezone

Is it possible to select the TimeZone in PreferenceScreen?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Storing an int should cover it. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7170293/645270) helps (scroll to the **edit** part)

Comment: I just hope for a user to input the destination time zone in PreferenceScreen. As before, I am writing down all Timezone information and use ListPreference to do it. After that, I also considered to use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() to have the arraylist. But I don't know how to implement in PreferenceScreen. So I post this question in here